# ImportError: cannot import name 'cpyHook' from partially initialized module 'pyWinhook'

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

This has been plaguing me for a while now, and I'm not sure what to do about it. I've tried modifying the **init**.py pyWinhook script's imports, but to no avail. Here's the whole error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\myuser\Documents\Python\evil_programs\keylogger.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pyWinhook as pyHook
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyWinhook\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .HookManager import *
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyWinhook\HookManager.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import cpyHook
ImportError: cannot import name 'cpyHook' from partially initialized module 'pyWinhook' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyWinhook\__init__.py)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Never mind. I fixed it.

Comment: can you please check share how you fix it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. I just uninstalled and installed it or something.

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed this is by installing Python 3.8.

Python 3.10 and 3.11 produced this issue.

I got this idea from the executable name on GitHub "pyWinhook-1.6.2.win-amd64-py3.8.exe"

Why it does not work with newer python, I have no clue.